# Understanding mirror modifier

Tags: mirror, axis

I'm quite new to Blender but certainly having fun!

I dont always feel like documentation is always as clear as i need it to be. Probably because i haven't fully grasped all the consepts just yet.

Anyway, I'm using mirror modifier and wondering why it starts to mirror from seemingly random place in mesh.

To me, this mirror should a) start from the end of the plane, not arbitrarily few faces overlaping like in the middle here and b) shouldn't this be end result when axis = X. Here i have Y axis selected and plane mirrors as it would be X axis.

[image]

Comment: If you want to see what @moonboots is talking about on-screen, go to the Object tab > Viewport Display panel, and turn on 'Axis'. That will show you the origin and orientation of your object, which, (unless you have assigned another,) is what the modifier will use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you mirror, the vertices you create will be created on the other side of the axis, with the object origin as center. If you choose the X axis and create some vertices on the +X side, they will be mirrored on the -X side, but if you create vertices on the -X side, they will be mirrored on the +X side as well. To avoid any trespassing you can enable the *Clipping* option, that way you'll make sure that if you move a vertex close to the axis plan, it won't trespass on the other side, but it won't delete the vertices that are already on the other side, like what's happening in your case.

As for your second question, the mirroring currently happens on the X axis while you've selected the Y axis, but actually the *Mirror* modifier takes the local orientation into account, not the global orientation. You must have rotated your object in *Object* mode, so its local orientation is not aligned with the global anymore. What you can do is apply the rotation of your object in *Object* mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Rotation*), then choose X in the *Mirror* modifier.

Comment: thanks! i set the origin properly and applied rotation and your explanation makes total sense!

Answer (score 1):

great to hear you're having fun! The object is mirrored around the object origin which can be repositioned using the options under Object > Set Origin menu (in the top left area of the 3D Viewport)
[image: Object > Set Origin menu]